# Attempting to use mod_wsgi in daemon mode show default apache "It works!" page instead of application

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, bottle

I've got a Python WSGI app that I've written and runs with apache2 + mod_wsgi in embedded mode, and I'm trying to get it to run in daemon mode.

Problem is, with the configuration (below), instead of seeing the app I see the default Apache2 "It works!" page which, despite the zeal with which it states its operational status, is wrong.

I have only sanitised the appname and urls etc, so you're seeing the entire apache conf that I'm using.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName app.example.com
  ServerAlias app

  WSGIDaemonProcess appname user=www-data group=www-data processes=5 threads=5 display-name=%{GROUP} maximum-requests=1000
  WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/share/app/app/application.wsgi

  Alias /static /usr/share/app/app/static

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/app/error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/app/access.log common

<Directory /usr/share/app/app>
    WSGIProcessGroup appname
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/app/app/static>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

No matter whether I put the WSGIProcessGroup option inside the  section, or just in the main  section, this still just shows the "It works!" page.

The app is using bottle and toscawidgets, with wsgi validator to make sure it's all behaving nicely. The code I use to construct the application:

```
import bottle
import tw.api
from wsgiref.validate import validator
#.... A whole buttload of code
application = bottle.default_app()
application = tw.api.make_middleware(application, stack_registry=True)
application = validator(application)
```

**Edit:** I'd also like to note that I've had this problem in both mod_wsgi 2.8 with Python 2.6.5, and mod_wsgi 3.3 with Python 2.7.3.

**Edit 2:** The alias for /static/ is still working, so I do appear to still be hitting the VirtualHost. If I comment out the WSGIProcessGroup directive and restart apache, it will run fine, but in embedded mode rather than daemon mode.

Comment: Did you read the "It works!" page?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be specifically anything wrong with the mod_wsgi parts of the configuration except that:

```
user=www-data group=www-data
```

is redundant as it will default to user Apache runs as and so they do not need to be set explicitly. Using maximum-requests is also not recommended unless you have a specific need.

The underlying issue is more likely that your whole VirtualHost definition isn't being used.

Add a syntax error into the VirtualHost to see if it is even being read by Apache. Adding a line with 'xxx' on it will suffice to trigger a syntax error.

If is being read, you need to look at whether named virtual hosts are enabled. Ie., does appropriate NameVirtualHost directive exist.

The next issue is whether the hostname given to ServerName is actually ending up at Apache. You obviously don't own 'app.example.com', but does what you are really using actually go to this Apache. Shutdown Apache and try again. If can't contact it, then that is likely right at least.

After that you need to make sure you don't have an existing VirtualHost which is trying to also serve for the same ServerName.

Comment: Thanks Graham. As I've just mentioned in my second edit, the /static/ Alias is doing it's job, so the VirtualHost is definitely being reached.

Comment: Set LogLevel to 'info' rather than default of 'warn' and see what messages mod_wsgi outputs.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you're not hitting this VirtualHost at all.  Do you have "NameVirtualHost *:80" anywhere?  Are you actually accessing the site via the app.example.com or app names?

Comment: Hi Michael, the alias for /static/ is still working, so I do appear to still be hitting the VirtualHost. If I comment out the WSGIProcessGroup directive and restart apache, it will run fine, but in Embedded mode (of course.)

Comment: And "NameVirtualHost *:80" is in /etc/apache2/ports.conf .

Comment: I know this is old but why is this an answer? How does this solve anything?